# how can I change imageview picture when I pressed

Tags: android

I have two pictures `a` & `b` .Currently, my `imageView` has image `a`.
I wanna change the image to `b` when pressed.
how can I do?
this is my code

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/prepage"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/aki_pre"
        android:onClick="@drawable/aki_preh"/>


private  ImageView.OnClickListener pagepre=new ImageView.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String result = dbQA.executeQuery(num+"");
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
            {
                JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                topic=jsonData.getString("Q1");
                Q1.setText(topic);                 
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: hello, Faisal, Is this code insert in ImageView.OnClickListener ?

Comment: yes, when you touch your image it will change image.

Comment: Faisal, I success to change image,but I have problem that I cant do anything....I hope when my imageview press,I will clean text, and jump to next question.but now it cant....

Comment: If your image change issue is solved, can you please accept this answer. If you have new problem please post new question and share link with me here, I'll try to help you out with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as simple

```
// when you click this demo image

image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.secondimage);
    //add some codes 
 }
}
```

Comment: I had been try this.but I hope when I am not touch this imageview.it will turn back to a.png

Comment: What do you mean turn back to a png?

Comment: The user press imageview , a image would turn to b. but when user not touch ,it will turn back to a image .

Comment: The image will not change to a after the event unless you have an another event to trigger back to a.png